# Unable to use subscribe output value in filter function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm hoping someone could help, in Angular 7 i'm currently calling in a Json file via a service, this is working fine and i'm able to output the object array, however what i'm trying so do then is filter the objects in the array by matching the value of a property named 'Id' with the the URL param id and ultimately having just that single object output on that page.

I'm using activatedRoute to get the active param Id, this is working great, however when I try and filter by **paramsId.id** it outputs an empty array but if I replace **paramsId.id** with a number I know is being used as an Id from one of the objects in the arrays it outputs fine, I can also output the **paramsId.id** in a console log fine but for some reason I just can't get it to work in the filter.

Works:

```
return animal.id === 5;
```

Doesn't work:

```
return animal.id === paramsId.id;
```

This is what I have inside my component ts file:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private animalService:AnimalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.animalService.getAnimals().subscribe(animals => {

      this.animals = animals;

      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(paramsId => {

        const filterAnimal =  this.animals.filter(function(animal) {
          return animal.id === paramsId.id;
        })

        console.log(filterAnimals);

      });

    });

  }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you get when you do console.log(paramsId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution doesn't work because paramsId.id is a string and animal.id is a number. "5" !== 5 so you need to parseInt(paramsId.id).

You should have a method on your service getAnimal that takes an animal id and returns a single animal

```
animal$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
  map(params => parseInt(params.id)),
  // parseInt is why your current solution is not working as string !== number
  switchMap(id => this.animalService.getAnimal(id))
);
```

and then use the animal$ observabal in your template with the async pipe.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="animal$ | async as animal">
  {{animal | json}}
</ng-container>
```

No subscriptions necessary.

In the service

```
getAnimal(id: number) {
  return this.getAnimals().pipe(
    map(animals => animals.find(animal => animal.id === id))
  );
}
```